# Number of states and alphabet to fulfill definition of DFA?

Tags: automata, finite-automata

I have some questions about DFA.

Can the alphabet of a DFA have one element?

Can a DFA have zero states?

Does a DFA require final state(s)?

Thanks

Comment: It's in the definition. Literally.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, the alphabet can have only one element. For example the DFA that recognizes a* has Σ={a}.
2. No. A DFA is defined as {Σ, Q, δ, q0, F}, where q0 is the initial state. So the number of states for a DFA is >= 1.
3. A DFA with no final states rejects every input, so it's an automaton that recognizes L=∅. So no, DFA doesn't require final states.